# Not changing screen based on Authentication Status Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to go to the home screen or stay on auth screen based on whether or not the user is successfully authenticated. Using Firebase authentication's authStateChanges and a stream builder.

I get no error codes and the console reads

```
D/FirebaseAuth(21665): Notifying id token listeners about user ( pG6pORODSGMi21fuaoql29hqXZp2 ).
D/FirebaseAuth(21665): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( pG6pORODSGMi21fuaoql29hqXZp2 ).
```

so the authentication is successful and when I hot restart the app it goes to the home screen and displayed info as it should.
Here is the code

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: _initialization,
        builder: (context, appsnapShot) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            routes: {
              SignupScreen.routeName: (ctx) => SignupScreen(),
              AuthScreen.routeName: (ctx) => AuthScreen(),
              HomeScreen.routeName: (ctx) => HomeScreen(),
              UserPhoneAdds.routeName: (ctx) => UserPhoneAdds(),
              PhoneAddForm.routeName: (ctx) => PhoneAddForm(),
              EditPhoneScreen.routeName: (ctx) => EditPhoneScreen(),
            },
            home: appsnapShot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done
                ? SplashScreen()
                : StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return SplashScreen();
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return HomeScreen();
                      } else {
                        return AuthScreen();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
          );
        });
```

FYI-this is off of a course and in the app it came from this works correctly
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The `authStateChanges` doesn't return a snapshot but a `User` as you can see in the officaial [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage):

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

So you sould just check if `User` is `null` or not.

Comment: Ok thanks. Was this part of a new update. Just wondering cause like I said in the OP, it works in another app with as far as I can tell the exact same code